# Author Post Specific Banners with Admin Control and Expiry system

Tags: wordpress

I have try to get answer from Wordpress Answer but instead of getting answer I earn Thmbleweed badge. :( anyways so I am trying here and hopping solution.

My new website going to have multiple author. All I need to do with that some specific system where Admin can add banner to the specific author's post.

Fore example xxx banner will only display on xyz author's post and not on any other author post. Which will have auto expiry system, it will automatically invisible when it reach to defined date by admin. All these systems will be under admin control only.

I am not php guy but can play with wordpress codes a bit. So I need really great help to work this out. I also won't mind to give full credit on my website credit display for this system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table with fields:id, authorid, banner_content, expiry_date.

> To fill in the table with specific details of authorid,
>   banner_content, expiry_date create a [simple form](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-MySQL-Creating-Form-Insert-Data-P280.html) or directly enter in
>   the database.

After your table is created and is filled with details

> **HERE IS THE COMPLETE CODE TO DISPLAY THE BANNER**

```
    <?php 
    $getid = $posts[0]->post_author; //No need to change this
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM bannertable wbanner WHERE author_id = $getid AND expiry_date>CURDATE();"; //change the table name 'bannertable' and field names 'author_id' and 'expiry_date' to your own
    $banner_con=$wpdb->get_results($sql);
    echo "<div class='banner'>";
    foreach ( $banner_con as $content ) 
    {
        echo $content->banner; //change field name 'banner'.
    }
    echo "</div>
    ?>
```

Make sure to enter the above code inside the loop of your theme.

Comment: Priya thanks for quick response. Appreciate. But I am new to all these can you please to write full code? I would really thankful for your help. Basically I am html css and cg artist not familiar with php and sql so much just playing with some snippet. I have started to learn few months ago.

Comment: Priyam thanks again. One question..as I mentioned I am new to all these. May be I sounds like stupid but can you please tell me will this code display banner at one place? and if i want to show many place can I repeat this code? I would be thankful if you can help me in more detail. However I will sure try meanwhile. You are really very helpful. Thanks

By the way I saw your profile, you are from India. Me too now working in Mauritius. good to see you :)

Comment: @pixelngrain ,  this will work inside the loop to display single posts on post pages. So just after the start of loop write the whole code except in place of `echo $content->banner;` write `$some_var=$content->banner` and after that you can do echo `$some_var;` at any place you want to display the banner in the same page.

Comment: @pixelngrain , if the post is helpful can you select it as answer so that i can cross that 50 mark in score so i can comment on other's answers here..

Comment: As I am still working on it and I will sure accept it once I will get result you dont worry about that.

However I have tried your snippet but I am getting blank div no content. Below is the code I have added

Comment: '<?php
   $auth_banner = $content->banner_content;
   $getid = $posts[0]->post_author; //No need to change this
   $sql= "SELECT * FROM bannertable wbanner WHERE author_id = $getid AND expiry_date>CURDATE();"; //change the table name 'bannertable' and field names 'author_id' and 'expiry_date' to your own
   $banner_con=$wpdb->get_results($sql);
   echo "<div class='author-banner'>";
   foreach ( $banner_con as $content ) 
   {
    echo $content->banner_content; //change field name 'banner'.
   }
   echo "</div>";   
  ?>'

Comment: and created table exactly with the name as you asked me for id i have created author_banner_id 2. authorid 3. banner_content 4. expiry_date

I have directly insert content to the database but nothing is visible except div with class banner <div class="banner"></div>

Comment: I have also noticed that if I am creating variable like '$auth_banner = $content->banner;' that is also doesnt work. Div only visible with full code but nothing visible with '$auth_banner = $content->banner;' Even there is no content visible even in source code. And even the DIV is visible to all author not only for defined  author ID

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6115/discussion-between-priyam-and-pixelngrain)